# OpenCV as a frameserver

Tags: video, opencv, avi

I am trying to do random access to an AVI movie.  I need to skip frames and move back and forth to exact positions in the movie.  When I do this I get a nasty jittery movie that moves the frames back and forth.  Is it possible to use OpenCV as a frame server?

```
cvSetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frameNumber );
image= cvQueryFrame( capture );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV Seek Function/Rewind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974625/opencv-seek-function-rewind)

Comment: I am using the same technique for this, but the problem is that it is not frame specific, so it jitters.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question and if you want to store frames, you can use `vector <IplImage*> frames` then push back each frame of the video to the `vector`. Then whenever you want, you can have access to your frames without `cvQueryFrame()` and you can show frames just like a movie with `cvShowImage()`.

Comment: hmm, that would work, but the movies are rather big, so I think I would run out of memory before I could store that many frames.