# Extract a frame at a specific time of a video and insert a text OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

So i have a video with a duration of 15 seconds and at a specific time i need to insert a text field. 
Until now my code just reads a video and displays it. After that we extract frames and calculate the duration of each frame.

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

# Create a VideoCapture object and read from input file
# If the input is the camera, pass 0 instead of the video file name
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('my_baby_dog.mp4')

# Check if camera opened successfully
if (cap.isOpened() == False):
    print("Error opening video stream or file")

# Read until video is completed
while (cap.isOpened()):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)  # OpenCV2 version 2 used "CV_CAP_PROP_FPS"
        frame_count = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
        duration = frame_count / fps

        print('fps = ' + str(fps))
        print('number of frames = ' + str(frame_count))
        print('duration (S) = ' + str(duration))
        minutes = int(duration / 60)
        seconds = duration % 60
        print('duration (M:S) = ' + str(minutes) + ':' + str(seconds))
        # Display the resulting frame
        frameWidth = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
        frameHeight = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
        cv2.putText(img=frame, text='EKO', org=(int(frameWidth / 2 - 20), int(frameHeight / 2)),
                    fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, fontScale=3,
                    color=(0, 255, 0))
        cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
        # Press Q on keyboard to  exit
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    # Break the loop
    else:
        break



# When everything done, release the video capture object
cap.release()

# Closes all the frames
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Obviously, you have a programming problem, so your post is appropriate here, However, you didn't actually ask a question, and I personally couldn't determine where exactly your problem is. Could you edit your question?

Comment: Since my video is 15 seconds i want to insert a text when time of video reaches 6 seconds (set a text into a specific time)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to add a text overlay after 6 seconds. Assuming this overlay will continue until the video is finished, you will want to add an `if` statement to compare the `duration` to the `start time` of your text overlay.
then display it.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

start_time = 6

# Create a VideoCapture object and read from input file
# If the input is the camera, pass 0 instead of the video file name
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('my_baby_dog.mp4')

........
while (cap.isOpened()):
    ........
        # ADD OVERLAY TEXT
        if start_time < duration:
            cv2.putText(img=frame, text='EKO', org=(int(frameWidth / 2 - 20), int(frameHeight / 2)),
                    fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, fontScale=3,
                    color=(0, 255, 0))
        cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
```

Likewise you could start and stop the text overlay like this

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

start_time = 6
stop_time = 10
    ........
        # ADD OVERLAY TEXT
        if start_time < duration < stop_time:
            cv2.putText(img=frame, text='EKO', org=(int(frameWidth / 2 - 20), int(frameHeight / 2)),
                    fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, fontScale=3,
                    color=(0, 255, 0))
        .......
```

Comment: As long the interval [start_time,stop_time] is always true as long as these values are inside the range of whole duration of the video so the text will always pop up on the whole video duration. I need a function that can seek in the video whenever i set a specific time. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: This post will show you how to seek in a video. [Seeking using openCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974625/opencv-seek-function-rewind)